# Spring webflux convert flux.bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration) which gives Flux<List<T>> to flux.windowTimeout(maxSize, duration).concatMap()

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Spring webflux and reactor offer a `.bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration)` operator, which gives a Flux<List> on a Flux

I am trying to achieve the same, not by using `.bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration)`, but using `flux.windowTimeout(maxSize, duration).concatMap()`

*What did I try:*

I tried using concatMap as follow: `flux.windowTimeout(maxSize, duration).concatMap(f -> f)`

*Issue:*

With the above code, I am getting a T, but I would like to get the same as buffer time out.

*Question:*

What is the correct combination of windowTimeout + concatMap which is equivalent to buffer time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the same behavior as bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration) using windowTimeout(maxSize, duration) and concatMap(), you can modify your code as follows:

```java
flux.windowTimeout(maxSize, duration)
    .concatMap(f -> f.collectList())
```

Explanation:

- **windowTimeout(maxSize, duration)** will create windows of elements based on the specified **maxSize** and **duration**.
- **concatMap()** will subscribe to each window as a separate Flux and emit their elements sequentially.
- By calling **collectList()** on each window Flux, you can transform each window into a single List emission, which will be equivalent to the behavior of **bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration)**.
- This modification ensures that instead of emitting individual elements, you receive a **Flux** containing the buffered elements after the specified **maxSize** or **duration**.

Please note that in this approach, each emitted List will contain the elements collected within the specified window, which may differ from the behavior of **bufferTimeout(maxSize, duration)** if the source Flux emits elements irregularly.

Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?